# Why would a Java/Maven project created on Windows, not run on Linux - Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I've created some browser automation as a Maven project with Selenium Webdriver, written in Java on my windows machine.

If I "cd "directory" mvn package" it from the CMD it compiles and runs.

When I send it to the server computer and ask the server guy to mvn package it, he gets the following error:

```
jenkins@ip-11-22-71-22:/mnt/www/jenkins/MailCheckerAndTestStarter/target$ java -jar functionalTests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
functionalTests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I forgot to change the firefox binary location in the code, but I dont think thats the problem...

EDIT: Should I provide the POM.xml?
Might that be a .classpath issue? 
I dont know anything about working with .classpath :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could happen because of encoding issues. Many IDE:s use some platform dependent encoding to encode its files unless you specify otherwise. It is a wise idea to use UTF-8 as encoding to make sure all the files are encoded in a platform independent fashion. How this is done depends on the IDE.

Also, it is wise to specify the encoding in Maven, as specified [in the official FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning):

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    ...
</project>
```